# Impersonate logged in user when accessing Azure Active Directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager

I use Azure SDK to retrieve the list of a resource groups:

```
const MsRest = require('ms-rest-azure');
const { ResourceManagementClient } = require('azure-arm-resource');
const credentials = await MsRest.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(appId, pass, tenantId);
const client= new ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);

const resourceGroups = await client.resourceGroups.list()
```

The problem however is that I receive all the resource groups in the subscription. I want to receive only the resource groups that the logged in user has access to. So one option is to retrieve the IAM (access control) list of a resource group and check if the logged in user appears there. I do not want to do it that way because it will requite many requests to Azure. I want to impersonate the logged in user when accessing Azure in order to get only the resource groups he is permitted to see.

I use passport-azure-ad for authentication.

Comment: Haven't done it in NodeJS but basically you need to have the user login using one of the interactive OpenId Connect flows, and then you can request for an access token to access Azure's APIs as them.

Comment: You could try something like `msRestAzure.interactiveLogin().then(credentials => {
    const client = new ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);
    // do whatever you need with client, like get resource groups list
});` to prompt user for credentials.. so that client works with user's permissions.   This would replace the code where you're currently getting the credentials with `MsRest.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(appId, pass, tenantId);` i.e. using service principal

Comment: @RohitSaigal I think it's for client side. It prints a message to the console: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code DYH0KLDQL to authenticate.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following code to receive only the resource groups that the logged in user has access to:

```html
var msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
var resourceManagement = require("azure-arm-resource");
 
// Interactive Login
msRestAzure.interactiveLogin(function(err, credentials) {
 var client = new resourceManagement.ResourceManagementClient(credentials, 'subscriptionid');
 client.resourceGroups.list(function(err, result) {
   if (err) console.log(err);
   console.log(result);
 });
});
```

And you could also refer to this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/tree/master/lib/services/resourceManagement).

Comment: I think it's for client side. It prints a message to the console: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code DYH0KLDQL to authenticate.